# is this style of writing correct in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery, many book tell me global var is bad, so I wanna ask the following codes is formal?

```
   $(function(){
        ;(function($){
            $("ul > li").addClass('emphasis');
        }(jQuery));     
   });
```

Comment: Your code has no variables (except the jQuery object), so... overkill!

Comment: You could just do `jQuery(function($) { ... });` to keep both the value of `$` and make sure the DOM is ready.

Comment: it is correct, but it's kinda pointless as-is. the outer-wrapper uses $ rather than jQuery, which makes the inner wrapper pointless. not to mention, the outerwrapper can accomplish the same goal that the inner wrapper is doing while also waiting for the dom to be ready. `jQuery(function($){ $("ul > li").addClass('emphasis'); });`

Answer (score 2):

```
(function($){
  // do whatever using $

})(jQuery);
```

The above is a good pattern since it protects you against conflicts with other frameworks that might use the $ variable name. It also gives you the benefit of keeping scope contained to the closure instead of polluting the global scope

This pattern is called a self calling closure.

Comment: On the other hand, it's not a DOM ready handler ?

Comment: @adeneo sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: It's not the same as `$(document).ready`, the self invoking function doesn't wait for the DOM to be ready, it just keeps the value of `$` contained in the scope.

Comment: Yes, agreed. That consumer of the code has to be aware of that

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would enclose your jQuery like this:

```
$(function() { // document ready
  $("ul > li").addClass("emphasis");
});
```

However, this question / answer is entirely opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is inside out. You pass the global `jQuery` to an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) as to alias it to `$` inside the IIFE scope:

```
;(function($) {
    // $ === jQuery inside this function regardless of noConflict of mode
    $(function(){/*...*/});
})(jQuery);
```

However, as you're using the [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler, you can use the following syntax as well:

```
;jQuery(function($) {
    //$ is an alias to jQuery in this scope even in noConflict mode
});
```

This makes the IIFE unnecessary as the DOM ready handler receives the jQuery object as argument.

These patterns are basically to make your code portable to environments that may have the `$` assigned to something different than jQuery, so you can still use `$` to safely reference jQuery even in these cases. For more info:

- [Official jQuery Basic Plugin Authoring tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)
- [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

---

However, if you're working on a site of your own and there are no plans to include Prototype or Mootools, you can safely use `$(function(){})` without worrying about these patterns.

I tend to do it anyway to be more resilient to future changes, even when the odds of overriding the `$` are close to nil. In that case, it is mostly because of personal preference.